# Why is my implicitly Copyable variable being moved?

Tags: rust

According to the [Rust reference](http://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#moved-and-copied-types) at the time of this writing:

> For types that contain owning pointers or values that implement the special trait Drop, the variable is moved. All other types are copied.

Below is my code. I will expect `Point` to be a copyable type. But it is getting moved and the following code will not compile with 0.13.0-nightly.

```
struct Point {
    x: uint,
    y: uint
}

fn main() {
    let p: Point = Point{x: 10u, y: 10u};

    let p1 = p;
    let p2 = p; //Error: p has been moved p1
}
```

The compile error states:

```
note: `p` moved here because it has type `Point`, which is moved by default
```

Why is `Point` not treated as a copyable type?

Comment: I updated your title to indicate that the problem has to do with "implicitly copyable" structs. Since these no longer exist, I expect that more people will have the same question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Copy` must now be added explicitly, guide was just not updated yet:

```
#[derive(Copy)]
struct Point {
    x: uint,
    y: uint
}

fn main() {
    let p: Point = Point{x: 10u, y: 10u};

    let p1 = p;
    let p2 = p; // Now works because it is Copy.
}
```

Comment: Why, if `Point` is copyable, would there be an error about assigning to `p2`? Isn't it just creating another copy?

Comment: @DrewNoakes I forgot to delete the error comment when writing the example.

Comment: Thanks for following up. Makes more sense now :)